# Javascript Bootstrap randomize checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have the following situation I can not solve. I would be very thankful if anyone had an idea:

My webpage contains a table of players. Each line (player) contains two checkboxes: One that selects if the player is active (checked) or not, the other which team he/she belongs to (checked=Team 1; unchecked=Team 2).

So each line looks sth like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input id="plyr2_active" type="checkbox" name="plyr_active[]" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="plyr2_team" name="plyr_team[2]" data-on-color="danger" data-off-color="success" data-on-text="RED" data-off-text="GREEN" checked value="1"></td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to add a button that, when clicked, will run a function that randomizes the teams of the ACTIVE players. Meaning that the players will be shuffled and half of them belong to one, the other half to the other team.

What I tried: Get all checkbox states in an array, then shuffle() the array and try to change the checked-state via bootstrap. Miserably failed :-(

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you clarify where you are having difficulty? Is it with gathering the states into an array, shuffling the array, or changing the table to reflect the revised array?

Comment: Well first of all how to get only the active player's numbers into an array. If I have this array I would use shuffle(array) and then try to read the first half of entries in this array and change the corresponding checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this should help to get you started. It shows how to pull a list of active players (using jQuery) from your table.

Assuming you have a button with an id of 'shuffleBtn':

```
<button id="shuffleBtn">Shuffle<button>
```

and a table with id 'players':

```
<table id='players'>
  :
</table>
```

-

```
$("#shuffleBtn").click(function() {
    var newPlayerArray = [],
        id = 1;
    $("#players tr td:first-child").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('input:first').prop('checked')) {
            newPlayerArray.push(id);
        }
        id++;
    });
    console.log(newPlayerArray);
});
```

This will display an array of the active players (assuming the first row is player 1, the second player 2, etc.) on the console.

Example: `[1,3,4]`

It then iterates each row () and grabs the first column (). Then for each of those it finds the first `<input>` and checks if the 'checked' property is present (this means the checkbox has been clicked).

I am just pushing the row index (starting at 1) so you may need to change how you interpret the associated player.